# When using Linq to EF, is EntityDataSource used much or raw Linq code used more often?

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

The EntityDataSource does not seem to provide much customizability at all, e.g. you can't seem to be able to tweak the insert/update commands(or you don't have to?). Do professionals mostly write raw Linq code to use in conjunction with Databound controls like Repeater?

Comment: did you see my answer? Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the scenario.

If you need a grid-like control, where users can view/edit/delete records (basically allowing them to directly modify DB records), then use a LinqDataSource.

If you want more control over the queries use Repeater and bind to a concrete `List<T>` (for example).

I prefer the latter, because it isolates logic into a DAL, where it can be tested and controlled more efficiently.